# subprocess.check_output in try/except runs and then throws exception

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using the following in a script:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output(file_path,shell=True)
except:
    print("Error: Unable to open file.")
```

This code works mostly as intended with the only problem being that it still throws an exception on successful operations.

I will be using this with Tkinter to display message boxes and don't want my users to receive an error every time they close their successfully opened file.  I am a bit of a novice and don't understand the subprocesses as well as I'd like to.  I was originally using .Popen but from what I read, check_output is the best way to catch the exception.

Is there something I am missing or an easy way to fix this?

Edit:  I checked the error via this method:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output(file_path, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)
```

it just returns

```
b''
```

When I add print(e), I get this:

```
Command '<file_path>' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

where the <file_path> is the actual path to the file.

I've also tried using .Popen and then .communicate() to view the output and error, but both return none whether-or-not .Popen has a target.  If there is no target, I also see this in cmd:

```
<file_path> is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Basically, I just want to throw an error if the target file path is not valid.  If it is valid, I want it to open the file.  I don't need to know the error, just that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: What exception are you actually getting?

Comment: Updated OP.  I have listed what I am seeing.

Comment: Though it's not a perfect answer, I decided to go with a pathlib option and basically check to make sure the path exists before using Popen, and if it doesn't, throw error.